# Linear transformation with inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

I'm a little confused with the following situation because inner products show up in this linear transformation.:

Take $\mathbb{R^3}$ with the standard inner product. Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R^3}$ so that $\langle a,b\rangle = 2$

$L: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}:x \longmapsto x - \langle x,a\rangle b$

How do I determine the eigenvalues of $L$? I want to see if $L$ is diagonalizable.

I always use a matrix to determine the eigenvalues but it doesn't seem the best idea to do that in this case.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c\in\mathbb R^3$ such that $c$ is orthogonal to both $a$ and $b$. Then $\{a,b,c\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^3$ and the matrix of $L$ with respect to this basis is$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\\lVert a\rVert^2&-1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Can you please explain how you get to that matrix because I don't see it.

Comment: There was a typo in my answer, which I have corrected. The first column comes from the fact that $L(a)=a-\langle a,a\rangle b=a-\lVert a\rVert^2b$. The secondcolumn comes from the fact that $L(b)=b-\langle b,a\rangle b=b-2b=-b$. Finally, the third one comes from the act that $L(c)=c-\langle c,a\rangle a=c$.

Comment: I see it now, thank you. Can I now say that the eigenvalues are 1 and -1? I would say that it's not diagonalizable because you have two times 1 as eigenvalue. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the eigenvalues are $1$ and $-1$ and, no, it is not diagonalizable. However, just saying that you have the eigenvalue $1$ twice is not enough to prove it. After all, the same thing occurs with the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix},$$which *is* diagonalizable.